# Win32 dialog: How to add a window that was dynamically added to a dialog to the tab order?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a win32 dialog with a text label, a user box (which is going to be filled a control thats created on the fly) and two pushbuttons. The user box has the focus set to begin with.

Now, in the `initdialog`, when I create a new control and add it to the userbox rect on the dialog, I actually want the focus to be on the control first and then go to the two buttons on tabbing and then back to the control. I tried using `SetWindowPos(hWnd,HWND_TOP,0,0,0,0,SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE);` to achieve this. But no help. I tried calling `SetFocus()` on the new control. The, the focus is set on the control on init, but when tab is pressed it goes on to the buttons and doesn't come back to the control. The focus just shifts between the two pushbuttons.

Any idea how I can add this newly created control to the tab order ?

Comment: Does your control have the `WS_TABSTOP` style set?

Comment: Yes it does. But still it doesn't work. I read that we need to call IsDialogMessage from the app's main message loop. What does it mean by main message loop?

Comment: The `while (GetMessage())` stuff in `main()`. The documentation should tell you what such a modified loop looks like...

Comment: Actually my dialog is a modal dialog . So I shouldn't be needing to call IsDialogMessage. It should automatically be handled by the windows manager.
- I have Modal dialog with two pushbuttons and I create a treeview control passing the dialog hwnd as the parent window. Then I make a call to SetWindowPass passing HWND_TOP so that the new window is on top (z-order)
- The control has WS_TABSTOP in its styles during creation.
- I tried different things to test .. like moving the control between the OK and cancel buttons (z-order only). But focus doesn't go to the treeview control at all on TAB

Comment: When you run a dialog box with `DialogBox()` the system will call `IsDialogMessage()` **with the handle of that dialog box**. Tab navigation in other windows will not work. You could use a message filter to work around this, but it'll take a bit of work to do. But your architecture sounds a bit weird; why are you creating another window on top of your dialog instead of another dialog box? (And why is your window not owned by the dialog?)

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear. I was just creating a new treeview control as a child of the dialog.  which I was referring to as the new window in earlier comment.

Comment: OH I see what you mean now. That's very weird. What happens if you add `WS_GROUP`?

Comment: Tried that too.. Wasn't working out.